# drop down menu in html5

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, nav

i have the following code which has navigation, i want to add sub menu/drop down to them. (say a drop down from categories). how should i implement that? please help

```
<nav>
    <div class="navbutton"><a href="...">contact us </a></div>
    <!-- <div class="navbutton"><a href="...">forum </a></div>-->
    <div class="navbutton"><a href="#">Categories</a></div>
    <div class="navbutton"><a href="Register.html">Register </a></div>
    <div class="navbutton"><a href="...">About Us </a></div>
    <div class="navbutton"><a href="...">Home Page </a></div>           
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of tutorials online on how to do drop down menus, but I recommend ignoring all of them and finding a good client side library and just using that.  There's no point in re-inventing the wheel.

This is especially true because you can still run into cross-browser issues that will make you envy the dead.

Search for "RIA libraries", "javascript gui libraries", etc...

For starters, here's a library I like:
http://isomorphic.com/

I am not affiliated with them in any way.